# Dynamically creating checkboxes from datatable values

Tags: c#

I am making a DTO creator. I am able get the table names and put them into datatable. The problem is, I must create checkboxes dynamically using these table names, and then be able to get whatever items checked. This is what I have been able to come up with so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string cbName = dtable.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            //Console.WriteLine(dtable.Rows[i][0]);
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
            box.Tag = i.ToString();
            box.Text = cbName;
            box.AutoSize = true;
            box.Location = new Point(10, i * 50); //vertical
            //box.Location = new Point(i * 50, 10); //horizontal
            this.Controls.Add(box);
        }
```

The `dtable` already has names and I create the checkboxes. However they are out the rendered area of the form, can see at most 10 of them. Also, how can I register which boxes are checked during runtime?

Comment: When you say "out of bounds", do you mean they are being rendered outside of the form's visible area?

Comment: yes, they are, let me correct that part

Comment: Why not just add a scroll bar? Or use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of absolute positioning?

Comment: yeah, that helped but the main issue is, i need to register them somewhere once clicked, how will i differ them from each other?

Comment: Add an event handler to each one in your loop? Iterate through the collection of `Controls` and get each value? Many ways that can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put your CheckBoxes in a List and then count the checked ones.

```
List<CheckBox> lstBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();

// create box
...

lstBoxes.Add(box);

// Checking for checked boxes (eg. on form exit)
var checkedBoxes = lstBoxes.Where(b => b.Checked);
```

Or when you're creating your checkboxes, add an event on checked changed :

```
box.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var senderAsBox = sender as CheckBox;

            if (senderAsBox == null) return;

            var state = senderAsBox.Checked;

            // Do you stuff then...
        };
```